# Confusion in Understanding NSString and its memory management in ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-management, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

This might be a basic question,but i am still unclear about it.

***1st Instance***: I will declare a string as weak,in the header file.

```
@property(weak)NSString *string1;

@synthesize string1;
```

Then in my viewDidLoad method,i will assign some dummy text to it...say string1=@"hello world";

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    string1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world"];
}
```

then in the viewDidAppear method i will print the value of `string1`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"%@",string1);
     //It gives me 'null'(remember string1 is of weak property )
}
```

***2nd Instance***: for the same string1(weak) i will assign same text to it in different way.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    string1=@"hello world";
}
```

then in the viewDidAppear method i will print the value of `string1`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"%@",string1);
     //It prints 'hello world'
}
```

What's wrong over here?...Is it a ARC issue or am lacking basic knowledge...Any further explanation about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked before.  Basically constant strings have different memory requirements to `NSString` instances which are constructed at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's print out the address of the both objects to clarify what's going on.

```
// $ clang a.m -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -O0 -g
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
    NSString *str0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str0"];
    NSString *str1 = @"str1";

    NSLog(@"str0 = %p", str0);
    NSLog(@"str1 = %p", str1);

    NSLog(@"\nsome heap address = %p", malloc(1));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is the following (on MacBook Pro early 2013)

```
str0 = 0x7fcd02c02fd0
str1 = 0x10854b098

some heap address = 0x7fcd02f00350
```

The address of 'str0' is close enough to the heap address. So this NSString object was stored in heap.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"str0"];
```

Thus this NSString object was under management by ARC.

But the address of 'str1' seems too far from the heap address. It might be stored in .data section or .rodata section or some sort of area. Because '@"str1"' is constant NSString literal. Never released from the memory.